# Cookies getting excluded in case of API calls hosted as application within the same IIS site

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, iis-10, microsoft-identity-platform

There is a asp.net webapp with angular frontend and asp.net web api2 backend. Here goes the URL details :

```
Web App: https://www.testapp.com
Web API: https://www.testapp.com/services/api
```

Azure AD with OpenIDConnect (authorization code flow) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp has been used to implement authentication.

Since both web app and the web api are considered as single app in this case, hence there is only one registration done in Azure AD with Redirect URI : https://www.testapp.com

Is is possible that cookies generated as part of Azure AD login flow for the Redirect URI: https://www.testapp.com gets excluded whenever there is a call made to the web api: https://www.testapp.com/services/api

When I navigate to the URL:https://www.testapp.com using browser, in that case Azure AD login flow gets triggered but now if I try to navigate to the URL: https://www.testapp.com/services/api/test/method I don't see the Azure AD login flow getting triggered.

Can anyone help me here how to fix this issue.

Comment: What is the order of navigation to web app and web api? Before going to Web API, do you go to Web App and authorize yourself?

Comment: I first go to the webapp: https://www.testapp.com I see the Azure AD login flow but now if I open a new window and try to navigate to the URL: https://www.testapp.com/services/api/test/method I don't see the Azure AD login flow triggered. https://www.testapp.com/services/api is hosted as an application within the main site: https://www.testapp.com

Comment: Why don't you host web api in different domain? It is always recommended to have decoupled systems.

Comment: This is a legacy app and in this implementation the apis are used by the frontend application only. It is kind of tightly coupled with the frontend application only.

Comment: I have not come across this use case till now. But, let me know if setting up the same Azure AD app on `https://www.testapp.com/services/api` url separately helps.